# Scrolling div within an absolutely positioned div

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting a div to scroll who's parent container is positioned absolutely.

http://codepen.io/establish/pen/zdFaL

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="stream page">
  <div class="stream-content">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut odio libero, posuere in tortor quis, malesuada ullamcorper ante. Morbi sed orci nisi.</h2>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="detail page">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0; 
}

.detail {
  background-color: blue;
  left: 425px;
}

.stream {
  background-color: green;
  width: 425px;
}

.stream-content { overflow-y: scroll }
```

Comment: I think you just need to add a `height` to your .container, .page and .stream-content elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the `.stream-content` div a height.

```
.stream-content { 
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6akz6/

Comment: You're right. Although I've just realised it's an enclosing EmberJS div in my app that needs the 100% height as well as this. I was being blind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the *stream-content* class to

```
.stream-content {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 200px; //Set according to your requirement
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `div.stream-content` is not restricted in height, its content makes it taller than `div.container` that's why scroller in it is inactive. But `div.container` has `overflow:hidden`, that's why you only see content being truncated and scroller inactive.

Additionally to solutions proposed in other answers you can make container of `div.stream-content` with scroller, and remove `overflow-y` rule for it:

```
.stream {
  background-color: green;
  width: 425px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEvrg